# Why Android cannot read the file to a File object?

Tags: android

This is my code to create a File Object. I am sure that the file is existing. However the file `length()` returns 0 and the `exists()` returns false too.

```
File uploadFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/DSC00050.jpg");
int totalSize = (int) uploadFile.length(); // Get size of file, bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

if `exists()` returns false means the file does not exist or not accessible. Make sure that the SD card is mounted and that your app has sufficient permission i.e. `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. I suspect this is the problem because you should get exception in that case.

The other thing is to log the absolute file path `uploadFile.getAbsolutePath()` and make sure that it is correct.

**Edit:**

Are you sure that your image is directly under the `DCIM` folder not `DCIM/Camera` ? Use any file browser in Android and check the file complete path. I do not see any other problems in the code.

Comment: If the path is Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/" only, exists() is true and length() is not zero.
When I change the path to a file not just a folder, the result will be false and zero.
I am sure that the file is exist

Comment: Are you sure that the file *exists* directly under the *DCIM* folder not under another sub-folder?

Answer (score 0):

After Writing `File uploadFile = new File(...);` it will not create the file itself.

AFAIK `If File.exists() is returning false, then file just doesn't exist yet.`

but yes You can create file by calling `file.createNewFile()`